# Select in Oracle Stored Procedure raises PLS-00428

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am very new to Oracle, and I have been put on a project that requires me to use it. I am trying to create a new stored procedure, the select statement works, but when I run the entire thing, it will say:

[Error] PLS-00428 (8: 9): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SSACHDEV.CheckServiceProviderDownload
as

tempInt number;

BEGIN

    Select 
        distinct(trunc(dateStamp)), 
        SVCProviderSTTSSEQID, 
        CaseNbr 
        into 
        "Date",
        PrividerId,
        CaseNumber
    from SVCProviderSTTS 
    Where (trunc(datestamp) between trunc(sysdate - 1) and trunc(sysdate));




   -- tskmgr.task_priority_download (CaseNumber, Id, tempInt);

END;
```

I figured I have to create a temporary table to store the results into then do a cursor to call the next procedure which I have commented out called tskmgr.task_priority_download(CaseNumber, Id, tempInt);

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: **UPDATE**

What I'm trying to do is get the results from the select statement and for each result pass them into 
    tskmgr.task_priority_download (CaseNumber, Id, tempInt);

I thought it would be simple enough but it's proving to be challenging, again any help on this would be GREAT, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd recommend against using a local temp variable called date. Something like myDate or Date1 or anything else would be preferable, in my opinion.

Second, you have to declare those variables -- Date, ProviderId, and Casenumber.

For example,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE...
as
   tempInt NUMBER;
   myDate NUMBER;
   caseNumber VARCHAR2(100);
   ProviderId NUMBER;
BEGIN
...
```

Lastly, even though it makes things a little verbose, I tend to prefix my variables so that I can tell they are variables. For example, I might have done this instead, but some folks would tell me it is wasteful and unnecessary.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE...
as
   tempInt NUMBER;
   l_Date NUMBER;
   l_caseNumber VARCHAR2(100);
   l_ProviderId NUMBER;
BEGIN
...
```

Naming my variables this way makes it easier to understand when I am doing a join or where clause and have column names the same as my variables -- which you do.

I am a little confused as to the error message though. I'll take one more look and update my answer if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I have created those variables, but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: I firgure I need a table to store these values into, so
table = select statement

Comment: You don't necessarily need a table. However, I may have missed something. Are you expecting 1 result? Or a bunch? If a bunch, this is not the way to do it. You should use a cursor to select the values as part of a record, and then send the record to the stored proc. If this is what you are trying to do, tell me and I will update my answer with info on how to do that.

Comment: This is indeed what I am trying to do (multiple values), I thought about it and I figured out I'm doing it wrong. I am now working with a cursor, and think I'm close to being done, but I get the error **[Error] PLS-00103 (29: 7): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
   delete exists prior <a single-quoted SQL string>
Th** My code looks like

Comment: I'm closer, only error is:
**[Error] PLS-00904 (26: 13): PLS-00904: insufficient privilege to access object PUBLIC.TSKMGR**

Comment: Congrats on progress so far. Ask DBA to grant execute on that proc perhaps.

Comment: I have DBA privileges and I did grant execute on that stored proc, still get the error though.

Comment: It sounds like a packaged procedure (based on what you wrote above). Did you grant execute on the entire package?

Comment: Each time I try to grant access to it, for some reason it switches back to No, any ideas?

Comment: Nothing immediately comes to mind, but knowing where the problem is should make it easier to ask another question. But are you granting execute on the package or the package body? I can't remember which you need to do, or if it is both, or what.